# List<MyType> to <Widget>

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to understand the casting system of Dart, in specific with flutter.

I have a List of my custom type I would like to fill in a TableRow, but I simply fail to use map for it. Can anyone help me to point out what my problem is? At the end I need a list of widgets for the children parameter.

```
TableRow(
    children: myList.map((MyType foo) {
            return <Widget>[new Text(foo.name)];
        }) as List<Widget>
),
```

The error I am getting is:

```
flutter: type 'MappedListIterable<MyType, List<Text>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' in type cast
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You basically have a list of list while it wants a list of widgets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do this:

```
TableRow(
    children: myList.map((foo) {
            return new Text(foo.name);
        }).toList(),
),
```

As Rémi says, you need to return a widget inside the map() function, not a list of widgets. And then convert the iterable to a List with `toList()` method.